# Передача строки из метода одного класса в другой класс. Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

Приложение коннектится с сервером и передает данные с помощью Retrofit 2. Так как приложение используется в разных местах на разных серверах, необходимо вводить вручную в `EditText` значение ip и порт.

Как потом передать введенный ip и порт в другие классы и подставить их в Retrofit?

Класс ввода ip и порта:

```
public class IpPort extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView txt;
    EditText inputipport;
    Button butsave;
    public String ip_port;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ipport);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        inputipport = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputipport);
        butsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.butsave);

    }

    public void onMyButtonClick(View view)

    {
       ip_port = inputipport.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(IpPort.this, NumberBatch.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

передать нужно сюда:

```
public class NumberBatch extends AppCompatActivity {
  public String b, q, a, androidId, anstsd;
  public class ServerRequest{
    @SerializedName("numb")
    public String numb;
    public void setnumb(String numb){
        this.numb = numb;
    }
    public String getnumb(){
        return numb;
    }
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    public void setname(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getname(){
        return name;
    }
    @SerializedName("numbtsd")
    public String numbtsd;
    public void setnumbtsd(String numbtsd){
        this.numbtsd = numbtsd;
    }
    public String getnumbtsd(){
        return numbtsd;
    }
  }
  public class AnswerFromServer {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;
    public void setid(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getid(){
        return id;
    }
  }
  private static final String TAG = "NumberBatch";
  private final String server = "http://192.168.8.113:8080";
  private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
  private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .baseUrl(server)
        .build();
}
```

Чтобы private `final String server` стала равной `ip_port`.

Comment: И в чем проблема то? Вы не знаете как через intent передать данные?

Comment: Знаю, но через Intent строку можно передать только в метод или функцию, а мне нужно просто в класс... я уже пытался так делать, но к сожалению в строку ничего не передалось..

Comment: Что у вас за класс "NumberButch" и зачем вы его наследуете от Activity? Зачем вам клиент в этом классе? Вам нужно подставлять ваш "server" в момент создания клиента.

Comment: В классе NumberButch вводится еще данные для передачи на сервер и в следующий класс, там вьюхи, поэтому наследуюсь от Activity

Answer (score 0):

Что у вас за класс "NumberButch" и зачем вы его наследуете от Activity? Зачем вам клиент в этом классе? Вам нужно подставлять ваш "server" в момент создания клиента.

```
Retrofit getClient(String server) {
  return new Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .baseUrl(server)
        .build();
}
```

И вообще, вам стоит почитать про архитектуру строения приложений. Сейчас самый используемый, покрываемый большую часть задач MVVM, также продвигается гуглом, [вот ссылка на ру версию](https://habr.com/ru/post/456256/).

Comment: То есть быстрого решения нет? и мне нужно переделывать приложение?

Comment: @Алексей, я не знаю как у вас всё реализовано там внутри, но для быстрого решения передайте это значение в конструкторе, опять же, если вы уйдёте от Activity. Но это всё муть, и лучше переделать сейчас, завтра нужно будет переделывать в 10-ть раз больше.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку)